# How can I reset the inventory of a merchant via console?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I don't like having to wait 48 hours before a merchant starts selling stuff again. Is there a wait x hours command for the console - where I just type it and it has the affect of having waited for x hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do two of the following:

bring up the command console and enter: resetinventory

or

You can perform a wait: I think by T and selecting the time of wait period.

http://www.gamespot.com/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/cheats/

Answer (score 4):

The command: `resetinventory` will reset the inventory of a target (select the NPC first) to its default.

If you are just doing this to make the merchant have more money, you should just add more gold into his inventory via: `additem f <insert gold amount>` after selecting the NPC.  After that just sell whatever you want.

In my opinion, 'roundabout' cheating like this is really no different than just giving yourself the gold directly anyway so why bother?

Comment: ResetInventory did not work. I tried that before asking here, maybe it's a bug with my installation. It's not for the Gold. I wanted Daedric arrows from the solitude fletcher. I finally "cheated" by adding 1000 daedric arrows and removing 8000 gold from my inventory.

Comment: ResetInventory doesn't work because merchants don't sell from their inventory, they sell from a special container nearby (usually under the floor).

Comment: Putting hundreds of thousands of septims in there via TCL doesn't break the cap of how much gold they can trade to the player-character which, in my current test, is 19 454.

Answer (score 0):

1. Easiest way seems to be adding gold to the shopkeeper, although elderscrolls.wikia states: "This gold may not go to your inventory when selling items to the vendor.
2. What I usually do is quicksave, attack merchant, quickload. It will randomly reset the shop inventory, so make sure you bought any item you wanted first.
3. The console command ""resetinventory" doesn't reset the shop, just the npc inventory.

Comment: Please don't talk to the other answers. They can't hear you. This site isn't a forum and we don't work like a forum does. (Answers should be self-contained solutions to the problem, addressed to the question-asker only.) I reverted your attempt to respond to (I'm assuming) spartacus's answer because it doesn't make any sense here.